# python xlrd time_tuple for entire column

Tags: python, excel, time

at the moment i can change a single value from an excel sheet into a python readable data format using:

```
x = sheet.cell_value(1,2)
time_tuple = xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(x, 0)
```

However, I have now a new variable which corresponds to an entire column such as

```
x = sheet.col_values(0, start_rowx=1, end_rowx=5)
```

and I would like to change them into time tuples like i did for the single value before.

I thought it was as simple as:

```
x = sheet.col_values(0, start_rowx=1, end_rowx=5)
time_tuple = xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(exceltime, 0)
```

But i get the following error

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'
```

So I think i'm not too far away and just need to change a few words perhaps?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
import datetime as DT
x = sheet.col_values(0, start_rowx=1, end_rowx=5)
times = [DT.datetime(*xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(item, 0))
         for item in x]
```

Comment: Thank you @unutbu that works, but I was looking at plotting the date and if I attempt to do this it will plot a line for the year, for the day, for the month and the other three data points. This is because the output is '2014, 8, 8, 0, 0, 0' and I wanted to plot the date. Does this comment make sense?

Comment: If `xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(...)` is returning the tuple `(2014, 8, 8, 0, 0, 0)` then you can convert the tuple to a `datetime.datetime` object by passing the tuple to `datetime.datetime` (as shown above). The `*` is for [argument unpacking](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/how-to-use-args-and-kwargs-in-python/).

Comment: i'm currently making you a virtual cup of coffee to show my gratitude.